# Receiving segfault while mallocing within an array of char pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm writing a simple c program that reads lines from a text file into a char **. In my main function, I create the char * array, allocate memory for it, and pass a pointer to the array to another function to populate each index in the array with a char * representing the content of each line in the text file.

For some reason related to my memory management I'm guessing, I'm receiving a segmentation fault on the third iteration of my while loop, which copies the string into the array of strings. Why is this?

My code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void getRestaurants(char ***restaurantsArray) {
    FILE *restaurantsFile = fopen("./restaurants.txt", "r");
    char *restaurant = (char *)malloc(50 * sizeof(char));
    char *restaurantCopy = restaurant;

    //fopen will return null if it is unable to read the file
    if (restaurantsFile == NULL) {
    free(restaurant);
    return;
    }

    int index = 0;
    while (fgets(restaurantCopy, 50, restaurantsFile)) {
        // segfault occurs the third time the following line is executed
        *restaurantsArray[index] = (char*)malloc(50 * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(*restaurantsArray[index], restaurantCopy);
        printf("%s", restaurantCopy);
        printf("%s", *restaurantsArray[index]);
        index++;
    }

    fclose(restaurantsFile);
    free(restaurant);
}

void main() {
    char **restaurantsArray = (char **)malloc(100 * sizeof(char *));
    char **restaurantsArrayCopy = restaurantsArray;
    getRestaurants(&restaurantsArrayCopy);
}
```

Expected Result:

```
firstline
firstline
secondline
secondline
thirdline
thirdline
```

and so on, if the provided restaurants.txt file contains:

```
firstline
secondline
thirdline
```

Comment: Why are you using a *triple pointer*? Why are you passing the argument by reference if you do not modify the value? Why are you allocating outside the function and freeing inside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `getRestaurants`, `restaurantsArray` is declared as `char ***Array`. In the line `*restaurantsArray[index] = …;`, it takes `restaurantsArray[index]` and attempts to use it as a pointer (by applying the `*` operator). But `restaurantsArray` is merely a pointer to the `restaurantsArrayCopy` in `main`. `restaurantsArrayCopy` is merely a single object, not an array. It is just one `char **`. In `getRestaurants`, using `restaurantsArray[index]` with anything but zero for `index` uses some undefined thing.

There is no need to pass `&restaurantsArrayCopy` from `main` to `getRestaurants`. Just pass `restaurantsArray`. This is a pointer to allocated space.

Then, in `getRestaurants`, instead of `*restaurantsArray[index] = …;`, use `restaurantsArray[index] = …;`, without the `*`. This will assign a value to an element in `restaurantsArray`, which is what you want to do. Similarly, remove the `*` in the `strcpy` and the `printf`.